# Unable to locate element against ZK frame work

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am doing a testing against ZK frame work 
with selenium IDE .. it works fine ..
but with selenium web-driver .. it did not
it shows that unable to locate an element with the selenium web-driver ..
the web driver can not locate an element in grid table .. 
I try to Scroll into view .. 
and I Try List ..
all of them did not work .. 
when I try with move mouse it works .. but I cant assert or verify ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://*****/>
<title>work it2</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">work it2</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/xxx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//li[2]/div/div/div/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>doubleClick</td>
    <td>//div[2]/div[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the Java code ..

```
driver.get("xxx");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[2]/div/div/div/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement ee = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]")); // Unable to locate the element 
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.doubleClick(ee).perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the table contains XPath expressions which you want to find by string comparison. To do so, find *table cells* those content equals the query string you're looking for.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='//li[2]/div/div/div/span']")).click();
```

Same applies to the other statement:

```
WebElement ee = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='//div[2]/div[2]']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how to locate an element in ZK application after I Click in a button .. and the grid table display .. and I can not locate any element inside it ..